# Android vertically align text and widget

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-xml

I'm using a text label and a radio group in a horizontal linear layout:

[image]

How do I set it so that the label (Sex) appears in the vertical center of the radio group? Currently it appears too high

The code for this portion of my layout is:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"
            android:text="Sex:" />

        <RadioGroup
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.6"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Male"
                android:id="@+id/input_button_male"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"/>

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Female"
                android:id="@+id/input_button_female"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"/>
        </RadioGroup>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could use `android:layout_marginTop="??"` within the Textview.
Alternately you could use `android:gravity="center_vertical"` within the Textview. Probably the latter.

i.e.

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Sex:" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.6"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Male"
            android:id="@+id/input_button_male"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Female"
            android:id="@+id/input_button_female"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"/>
    </RadioGroup>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Do you want like this then put in your textview below code

```html
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
```

Answer (score 2):

Check this out!

`android:layout-width="0dp" not recommended! Prefer androd:layout-width="wrap_content"`

[image]

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:orientation="horizontal">

<TextView
    android:layout_marginLeft="48dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:layout_weight="0.4"
    android:text="Sex :"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<RadioGroup
    android:layout_marginRight="72dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.6"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/input_button_male"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:text="Male" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/input_button_female"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:text="Female" />
</RadioGroup>
```